# Wordpress: save_post missing $_POST everytime i try doing 'save_post'

Tags: php, wordpress

```
<?php
    use \Core\Core;
    use \View\View;
    use \Assets\Asset;

    class PostHook implements \Core\Page
    {
        public static function make() {
            return new PostHook;
        }

        public function load()
        {
            add_action('load-post.php', array($this, 'loadPostMeta'));
            add_action('load-post-new.php', array($this, 'loadPostMeta'));
            add_action('init', array($this, 'init'));

        }

        public function init()
        {
            add_action('save_post', array($this, 'savePostMeta'), 11, 2);
        }

        public function loadPostMeta()
        {
            add_action('add_meta_boxes', array($this, 'addMetaBoxes'));
        }

        public function addMetaBoxes()
        {
            add_meta_box(
                    'cad-attachment-box',
                    'Downloadable Attachments',
                    array($this, 'showMetaBox'),
                    'post',
                    'side',
                    'high'
                );
        }

        public function showMetaBox($object, $box)
        {
            $options = array(
                    'object'    => $object,
                    'box'       => $box,
                    'value'     => get_post_meta($object->ID, '_downloadables', true)
                );


            echo View::factorize('posts/meta_hook.html.twig')->load($options);
        }

        public function savePostMeta($post_id, $post)
        {


            $meta       = isset($_POST['_downloadables']) ? $_POST['_downloadables'] : 'none'; 
            $oldMeta    = get_post_meta($post_id, '_downloadables', true);

            if($oldMeta == '' && $meta) {
                add_post_meta($post_id, '_downloadables', $meta, true);
            }else {
                update_post_meta($post_id, '_downloadables', $meta);
            }
        }

        public static function post()
        {

        }
    }
```

please note that the `load()` function is called on instantiating the whole plugin.

Everytime i tried saving the `_downloadables` to the `wp_postmeta`, it always return `'none'` due to my `isset()` code inside the `saveMeta()` function. i have tried

- adding priority to `save_post`
- dumping to `save_post`
- catching the `$_POST` but it always fails. any advice why?
- the `$_POST` does not have any data if i tried to var_dump it or save the whole `$_POST` insdide the `wp_postmeta`

Comment: There is no `saveMeta()` function...are you referring to `savePostMeta()`?

Comment: Why are you switching between `_downloadables` and `downloadables`?

Comment: i'm not switching, where did you get that notion?

Comment: This line: `$meta = isset($_POST['_downloadables']) ? $_POST['downloadables'] : 'none';`

Comment: it obviously mean that i'm checking if the index is available or not..

Comment: Yes, quite obvious. So you do not notice a difference between `_downloadables` and `downloadables`?

Comment: that's a obviously a typo. quick changed it.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/52125/discussion-between-gian-crescini-santillan-and-monkeyzeus)

Comment: Is it still broken? If yes, then you can try encasing the shorthand conditional `if(){}else(){}` block in parenthesis like this: `$meta = (isset($_POST['_downloadables']) ? $_POST['_downloadables'] : 'none');`

Comment: even if i'll put any $_POST inside, it still is empty.

let me clear it out in the query, the whole $_POST is empty.

Answer (score 0):

This is likely happening because you don't have a default value on the second argument in your  function, and are not specifying a number of arguments in your `add_action()` - this is the 4th argument after "handle", "function", and "priority". The result is that the call to `savePostMeta()` fails because of this missing argument as there is no default value. There are a couple ways to correct this - add the missing argument to `add_action()`, give `$post` a default value, or remove the `$post` argument altogether as you aren't using it.

- Option 1: Update `add_action()`

  ```
  // Priority 10 (default) and 2 arguments
  add_action('init', array( $this, 'init' ), 10, 2 );
  ```
- Option 2: Give `$post` a default value

  ```
  // Give $post a default value of "false" in case it isn't passed in
  public function savePostMeta( $post_id, $post=false ){
      // ...your code
  }
  ```
- Option 3: Remove `$post` since you aren't using it

  ```
  // Only use a single argument to your function
  public function savePostMeta( $post_id ){
      // ...your code
  }
  ```

FWIW I would go with Option 1/2 since it is "correct" and more future proof in case you *do* want to use `$post` in the future. You can also generally clean up your code as below - `$meta` with *always* be set for example, and you can just make a call to `update_post_meta()`, not need to fetch the value or call `add_post_meta()`:

```
add_action('init', array( $this, 'init' ), 10, 2 );

public function savePostMeta( $post_id, $post=false ){
    $meta_key = '_downloadables';
    $meta_value = isset( $_POST[$meta_key] )? 
        $_POST[$meta_key] : 
        'none'; 
    update_post_meta( $post_id, $meta_key, $meta_value );
}
```

Comment: And after I thought about this for a second, based on what you are trying to do, it probably makes more sense to filter the meta_value update rather than hook into `save_post`. As is is the meta value will be saved, and then saved again by your code but using `add_filter` you can change the value to 'none' as needed before any database updates happen.

Comment: See http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/update_(meta_type)_metadata